# MySQL: why is "1+1" treated as "1" in this query?

Tags: mysql, where-clause

All of the following queries return the row with ID == `1`, why is that?

`` SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE `ID` = "1"
SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE `ID` = "1+1"
SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE `ID` = "1 WTF" ``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When MySql performs a comparison it will do a data type conversion when the data types of the two compared values are not the same. In this case `ID` is numerical, and you compare it with a string. So MySql will convert the string to number. It does this by reading the digits at the start of the string, stopping as soon as it no longer understands it as a number.

In all three examples you provided that number is 1.

You can read about this in the MySql documentation: ["Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html)